# Cocoa Core Data Document Based Application underlying or read/write file type

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, document-based

I am writing a data editor tool for some of our mobile apps. Right now, I'm setting it up as a Document-based Core Data application. We're going to want to save the data as plain JSON or XML for including with the apps. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to open or write a JSON/XML file when using NSPersistentDocument. Is there a good way to do this, or should I just toss out Core Data and keep the info in memory, and write when the user tells me to?

Comment: I’m not sure why you’ve chosen Core Data in the first place. Have you written a custom Core Data atomic store that uses JSON instead of SQLite?

Comment: I have not written a custom atomic store yet, no. As for why I chose Core Data, it seemed like a good idea at the time, as far as keeping track of all the info on the screen. Coming back to the project now after a couple of months, I'm not really sure if I need Core Data, at least integrated into the document model.

Comment: I see. I have now idea how hard it would be to create a custom JSON store. You probably want to read [Atomic Store Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AtomicStore_Concepts/Articles/asFundamentals.html)